# What's the distinction between "nonessential" and "inessential"?

Tags: word-choice, adjectives, negation, prefixes

I'm revising a text that uses the word "nonessential", but my ear is telling me "inessential."  Usually when there are two very similar words like this, there is some subtle (or not so subtle) distinction between them.  Does anyone know what it is, and if so, can you cite any authorities who discuss the distinction?

Comment: This question is worth generalising the distinction between *non-* and *in-* prefixes.

Comment: @Benjamin I am not answering questions that specialize (in) the general.

Comment: should that be a philosophical context, I guess (without further information) *nonessential* (or: *non-essential*) is preferable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Non-essential** means *not absolutely necessary*, whereas **inessential** is more disapproving and can connote *trivial*.

According to Oxford Dictionaries Online, the prefix **non-** expresses a neutrally negative sense when added to adjectives, especially when the prefix **in-** has a special (I would say strongly negative) connotation. Another example is **non-human** (= *not human*) and **inhuman** (= *cruel*).

http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/non-?q=non-

Comment: I think that in the case of *non-human* and *inhuman*, the former *human* is a substantive, while the latter an adjective.

Comment: @Benjamin: It is both, actually.

Comment: I have doubts about *inhuman* being used as a substantive. At least I cannot remember a context in which I have read that. I can imagine however a *non-human being*, i.e. used adjectively.

Comment: @Benjamin: I was referring to "non-human" only. "Inhuman" is always an adjective.

Answer (score 3):

According to [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/inessential):

> **inessential**, *adj*. **1** : having no essence, **2** : not essential; **unessential**
>
> **nonessential**, *adj*. : not essential : not of prime or central importance

If the text is attempting to convey *unimportance*, then **nonessential** is the choice. If, however, the text is saying that something has no essence, then **inessential** is the word to use.

**Edit**: Note that the *noun forms* of **inessential** and **nonessential** have the *same definition*: *something that is not essential*.

Answer (score 2):

The *non-* prefix expresses negation as an innate quality while the *un-* or *in-* may express negation as an acquire quality. It seems however this nuance is very weak and varies depending on the semantics.

For instance:

> "His activities are unproductive, you should hire someone more qualified."
>   "His activities are non-productive, he merely is a consumer."

Perhaps more clearly:

> "His work is non-scientific, he is a pizza-deliverer."
>   "His work is unscientific, he has no proof to support his evidence."

Another example:

> "This file is unreadable, it was damaged"
>   "This file is non-readable, only a specific software can make sense of it."

The nuance with *-essential* however is very vague, in my opinion, because something is either essential or it is not. You could argue something is not essential enough and therefore "inessential" against something that absolutely isn't essential and therefore "non-essential", but I cannot think of any example where that would make sense.

It also seems that the use of those prefixes sometimes depend on the part of speech the word belongs to:

> non-human *(substantive)*
>   inhuman   *(adjective)*

It seems also seem to depend on the word derivation--but I am not so sure about that.

Answer (score 0):

As the site editors frequently utilize the noun *distinction*, I considered the question at hand in terms of the adjectives *indistinct* and *non-distinct*, and noted a conspicuous difference in the prefixes' applications: "Indistinct" specifies a *relative* lack of the quality of distinctness, while "non-distinct" specifies a *complete* lack of the quality of distinctness. As mentioned above in this discussion, however, applying that reasoning to the adjective *human* becomes problematic due to the moral implications when the prefixes are applied.