# Can "few" be used as a substantive?

Tags: grammaticality, nouns, adjectives

I feel doubts regarding the usage of *few* as a substantive. The sentence is:

> "Both kinds of literature are the product of the academic few."

Is this correct?

Now I want to place the adjective *fluent* to qualify *the academic few*:

> "Both kinds of literature are the product of the fluent academic few."

It sounds odd, but that's perhaps because of the f's?

What do you suggest?

Comment: sure, why not? It sounds OK. A tiny bit stilted. But acceptable to the audience that the context seems to be for

Comment: Why don't you make it an answer? :) Perhaps I should use a synonym for "fluent" that sounds better against "few".

Comment: +1 for Benjamin. Grammatically it's fine but "fluent few" doesn't exactly roll off the tongue.

Comment: Actually I think the "fluent few" has a nice ring to it.

Comment: Modifying a quantifier is tricky; most will not accept the bridle or float away. But it's not impossible, if one doesn't expect too  much for the effort. I think it would be better to speak of _**a** fluent academic few_. There's no reason to expect this sentence to convey a claim that it's the **same** few fluent writers in academe that're responsible; that's asking too much of an odd expression.

Comment: I don't know, "fluent few" tends to come out as "fuent flew" when I try to say it...

Comment: "The flaunty fool flicked, flapped and flipped his tong flabbily, but flubbed. Flabbergasted at the fool's flimflam, the flatulent flautist of few flutes flinched letting the flavory flan fall flat on the floor in a flop." :)

Comment: Yes, by the fluent few.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Certainly, as in these two citations from the OED:

> The favour of the few may silence the clamour of the many.
>
> A life not for the many, but for the few.

But most famously,

> Never in the field of human conflict was so much owed by so many to so
>   few.

No definite article there, but Battle of Britain pilots have ever since been known as 'The Few'.

Comment: +1 for the famous citation; it makes an excellent point.

Comment: +1 especially for not being distracted by the flu, I mean, the fluent few. The others focused more on the specific than the general.

Comment: @Kris: - 1 for your [inconsistence](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/54287/whats-the-distinction-between-nonessential-and-inessential/54292#54292) regarding your interest in the specific and the general :)

Comment: @Benjamin: My comment at OP was a mere pun, as you could have seen, and so it is here as well. :)

Comment: @Kris: I know :)

Comment: @Benjamin And I had **up voted** you on that inconsistence page.